# Office 365 Mail API - How to include user's signature

Tags: office365api

My Asp.Net web application is sending email on behalf on the logged user using Office 365 Mail API (Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices client lib).

How can I include the user's signature (defined in Office 365 user account) inside the body of the email ?

Answer (score -1):

The **signature** is a feature which belongs Outlook online. The Office 365 REST API only provide the mail service. However you can set the message content contains the **signature** in the app as you want.

For example, here is an example that use the Html format to set the message content contains the signature:

```
{
    "subject":"Test signature",
    "body":{"contentType":"html","content":"<html><head></head><body><div>Your Message content</div><div>Your signature</div></body></html>"},
    "toRecipients":[{"emailAddress":{"name":"user1","address":"user1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"}}]
 }
```

Comment: My goal is to re-use the same signature defined in their O365 mail settings. I don't want to duplicate and manage their signature in my app.

Comment: It is not support yet at present. If you want this feature for Office 365 REST, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thinking the other way around, I could set the signature in a custom user property in Azure AD, and retrieve it via claim in my app. But as I said my goal is to have a single signature to maintain, so is there any way to configure Office 365 to use signature from an user custom property in AD ? Or some kind of hook that could be used to sync signature to AD when it is changed in O365 mail settings ?

Comment: As I statement, the signature is a feature of Outlook online. We are not able to re-user it when we use other client like Outlook client, EWS. The only suitable way is enable users add the signature in your app and use that signature in your app.